# Notation question on $C(\mathbb R)$.

Tags: notation

In a definition of Paley-Wiener space, I have read
$$\{f\in L^2(\mathbb R)\cap C(\mathbb R),\ \operatorname{supp}\hat f\subset [-\pi,\pi] \}$$
I know $L^2(\mathbb R)$. What is $C(\mathbb R)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be the space of the continous functions